# Array type is used as a reference type argument in the function call

Tags: c++, qa-c

I am using PRQA QA C++ as source code analyzer.

This is the first code I analyzed :

```
    void test1(int * var);

    void example1()
    {
        int var1[10];

        test1(var1);
    }
```

QA C++ told me

> Array type is used as a pointer type argument in the function call.

So, I tried this following example (as it suggested) :

```
    void test2(int (&var)[10]);

    void example2()
    {
        int var2[10];

        test2(var2);
    }
```

This time, it told me :

> Array type is used as a reference type argument in the function call.

Is there a better solution to use an array parameter ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this PRQA software. Are these messages errors, or warnings, or simply information or explanatory in nature? Is there documentation that explains why they are generated or how they should be interpreted?

Comment: I don't understand. Is the analyzer complaining about using a reference to an array?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think it's complaining about the decay.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher But `void test2(int (&var)[10]);` doesn't decay. Only the first solution has an array decaying to a pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh yes, my bad...

Comment: These messages indicate "potential problems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original warning is fine, the second warning is also true.

This is due to arrays decaying to pointers, so `var1`, originally an array of integers can be used in an expression requiring a pointer.

If you really want to remove these, there are several options:

```
std::array<int, 10> var1;
test1(var1.data());
```

Of better:

```
void test2(std::array<int, 10>& var);

void example2()
{
    std::array<int, 10> var2;

    test2(var2);
}
```

Then the second option fixes the size of the array. If it needs to be variable but fixed at compile time, use a template, otherwise use a `std::vector` instead of a C-style array.